# Set up Custom nodes in Quorum

Tags: network, quorum, enode

I have gone through the https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples and it works good and fine. Now I want to make my own custom node Quorum Network what is the best method, tool or any guide available to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I made a quorum network(ibft) using ansible as a tool to raise the validators and regulars nodes. I have also created dockerfiles.i gu If you want you can review the documentation at https://github.com/everisblockchain/lacchain and use that as guide.